# How to get the corrupted table from a log file in hex?

Tags: mysql, corruption

I'm running a Magento 2 site, everyday we have a MySQL shutdown because of some corrupted data, we don't know the table causing the issue, this is what the error logs shows:

```
 Version: '5.7.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.c5OkKsNidi/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu)
2019-05-19T06:17:30.001609Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190519  6:17:29
2019-05-19T06:17:37.299075Z 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed file read of page [page id: space=28974, page number=1]. You may have to recover from a backup.
2019-05-19T06:17:37.299098Z 2 [Note] InnoDB: Page dump in ascii and hex (16384 bytes):
 len 16384; hex asc                     u6              q.   ...   ' x         ' x   ' x      .... u6  ;
InnoDB: End of page dump
```

Any ideas? Doing a MySQL restart does the trick but I need to do it manually, we need to be sure the db is fixed, but we can't get the name of the table.